# Lookup Field in LINQ to Sharepoint sometimes doesnt get retrieved

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

Im trying to use a LINQ to SharePoint to retrieve and filter a simple list with lookup field

```
  var list = _db.Leaves.Where(x =>x.Employee != null && x.Employee.Id == empId).ToList();
```

problem is sometimes randomly the Field Employee is null ! i dont know why ! its so strange that it happens randomly which cause it to throw casting exception, any one know why this is happening ?

```
<Field Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Employee" Required="True" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="Lists/Employees" ShowField="EnFullName" ID="{26183411-9bbf-48a1-b2f8-3388b98c7fef}" Name="Employee" ColName="int2" RowOrdinal="0" Indexed="TRUE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Restrict" />
```

Comment: why x.Employee is null? Seems data issue. You need to check the Leaves data (in debugger, or in DB). Why throwing exception, possibly because x is null, or x.Employee.Id is null. Share stacktrace. Update the question with more information and clear intent.

Answer (score 0):

Employee will be null if there is no value assigned to that field.

Just because it's a required field doesn't mean that the field will always have a value.  The "required" only applies to the web form form that list, it's not a restriction on the actual database itself.  For example, in code you can create/edit an object and set that field to null without any problems, even though it's required.  If you have a document library when you upload a document it creates the list item but populates none of the fields; it's not until the item is later edited that the lookup will be non-null (even if only accessed through the out of the box web UI).  There are other examples, but the idea remains.  In SharePoint you need to null check required fields.